# Is this a way to prove there are infinitely many primes?

Tags: prime-numbers, recreational-mathematics, divergent-series

Someone gave me the following fun proof of the fact there are infinitely many primes. I wonder if this is valid, if it should be formalized more or if there is a falsehood in this proof that has to do with "fiddling around with divergent series".

Consider the product

$\begin{align}\prod_{p\text{ prime}} \frac p{p-1} &= \prod_{p\text{ prime}} \frac 1{1-\frac1p}\\&=\prod_{p\text{ prime}}\left(\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac1{p^i}\right)\\&=(1+\tfrac12+\tfrac14+\ldots)(1+\tfrac13+\tfrac19+\ldots)\ldots&(a)\\&=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac1i&(b)\\&=\infty\end{align}\\\text{So there are infinitely many primes }\blacksquare$

Especially the step $(a)$ to $(b)$ is quite nice (and can be seen by considering the unique prime factorization of each natural number). Is this however a valid step, or should we be more careful, since we're dealing with infinite, diverging series?

Comment: It takes some work to make it rigorous, but yes, this is one proof of the infinitude of primes. As you say, equality of (a) and (b) are fuzzy, but you can replace $p$ with $p^s$ for $s>1$ everywhere and get the equality on both sides. Or you can just take $s=2$ and, if you know $\sum\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ and that $\pi$ is transcendental, then you know there are infinitely many primes.

Comment: You could say this: *if* there were finitely many primes then all the products and sums up to (a) would be finite, and yet due to unique prime factorization the product in (a) must be at least $\sum_1^n \frac{1}{i}$ for all $n$ so the product can't exist (by the divergence of $\sum \frac{1}{i}$), and thus there must be infinitely many primes.

Comment: The proof actually works somewhat different : It is assumed that the number of primes is finite. Then the given product would be finite, so the harmonic series would converge. This is not the case, hence the assumption, that only finite many primes exist, must be false.

Comment: In fact, using only the more basic fact that every number has a prime factorization, you have $(a) \ge (b)$, so you don't really need the fundamental theorem of arithmetic here.

Comment: @Solomonoff'sSecret You don't need *unique* factorization, just factorization, to connclude that :)

Comment: This is the way Euler did it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_theorem#Euler.27s_proof.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews like the Zeta[2] solution, hadnt seen that before.

Comment: @aronp It might well be circular - either the proof of $\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ or the proof that $\pi^2$ is irrational might require infinitely many primes, for all I know.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews - its not, seen quite a few proofs of Zeta(2) and non involved primes.  Your proof is nice, get over it.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem#A_rigorous_elementary_proof

Comment: @aronp I was more concerned about the fact about $\pi$. But it is cute, if non-circular. I'm just naturally cautious. :$

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The rigorous approach, as noted in comments.

If there are only finitely many primes, pick an $n$ so that:

$$H_n=\sum_{m=1}^{n}\frac{1}m > \prod_{p}\frac{1}{1-\frac 1p}$$

You can do this because the right side is a finite product of positive real numbers, and the series $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac1m$ diverges.

Next, show that:

$$\prod_p \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{p}} > \prod_p \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \log_{p}n\rfloor} \frac{1}{p^k}>\sum_{m=1}^{n}\frac{1}{m}$$

Reaching a contradiction.